# Requires installation of untrusted packages in every installation

Tags: updates, software-center

I am very new to Ubuntu and am pretty much using it as a refuge from Windows 10.

This being said I really have no prior knowledge in Ubuntu or anything computer related. I've had this problem for a while now, and it's almost definitely user error, I know, where I can't download anything from software center because it says the packages are untrusted (I have looked into some of the other threads that answer this question, none of them seem to work), and when I hit okay when the popup appears, the installation stops completely, so when I hit repair the popup re-opens repeatedly and it seems to install a whole lot of packages that I guess just decide to not exist.

You've probably guessed by now that I... am bad with computers. Please help

[image: Software Center popup]

[image: Error Codes after updating in the terminal]

Comment: I need help! getting a macbook has never been so tempting! Don't let me fall to the dark side!